# Runtime.getRuntime().exec does not work when run with jar file from powershell

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, runtime.exec

I have a code piece about killing the chrome drivers on **Selenium/Java**:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /f /im chromedriver.exe");
```

When I run this code piece in **Eclipse**, it works and kills all drivers but when I create jar file from same project and run this jar, `exec` command does not working and does not kill drivers.

```java
public class CommonKillAllDrivers {
    public void killAllDrivers() throws InterruptedException {

        try{
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /f /im chromedriver.exe");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error in catch");
        }

    }
}
```

This code is called from `afterTest` method:

```java
    @AfterTest(alwaysRun = true)
    public void killDrivers() throws InterruptedException {

        CommonKillAllDrivers killDrivers = new CommonKillAllDrivers();

        killDrivers.killAllDrivers();

    }
```

So I want this: all opened drivers while created with tests are killed at the end. ( I am observing these `chromedriver.exe` in Task Manager)

But when I run `jar` file from **Powershell**:

```
 java -jar "C:\Users\mervey\eclipse-workspace\tvb2b\target\b2b-selenium-jar-with-dependencies.jar" "C:\Users\mervey\eclipse-workspace\tvb2b\testng-suite.xml"
```

...this line of code is not working and not kill drivers.

Comment: Try running jar with admin permissions

Comment: First of all thanks for quick response and sorry I am so  new about these issues. I dont know how can I run jar with admin permission.Can you share with me please? @DeepeshChoudhary

Comment: I opened powershell with admin priveleges and run my jar but it does not work. drivers are not killed

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters. After making the necessary corrections / tweaks, run the Jar from the command line and report any output.

Comment: Still exist :(  I dont understand why eclipse can kill processes but when I run jar file from cmd it is not work

Comment: can you share an example about Process Builder to kill chrome drivers with me please?